# Joint density of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{(xy-2x-2y+4)}{32}$; $2\le x \le y \le 6$ for random vars $X$ and $Y$; find $P(X \gt 3 \mid Y = 5)$

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: What do you think you should do?  What trouble are you having doing it?

Comment: IS this a homework problem?

Comment: You are repeatedly posting questions like this without showing your effort. We are not here to do your homework problems.

Comment: @Graham Kemp feedback is welcome

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't have any close votes on it.

Answer (score 2):

Notice $xy-2x-2y+4 = (x-2)(y-2)$

Then $$\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=\tfrac{1}{32}(x-2)(y-2)\mathbf 1_{2\leq x\leq y\leq 6}
\\[1ex]f(x,5)&= \tfrac{3}{32}(x-2)\mathbf 1_{2\leq x\leq 5}
\\[3ex]\mathsf P(X>3\mid Y=5) &= \dfrac{\int_3^5 (x-2)~\mathrm d x}{\int_2^5(x-2)~\mathrm d x}\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: Hello @Graham, please can you help me solving the question? in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291176/specify-the-area-of-interest-to-find-the-marginal-pdf

Comment: @Graham do you tutor?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with so far, where

$f_{X,Y}(X = x/Y = y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$

$\Rightarrow f_Y(y) = \int_{2}^{s} \frac{1}{32}(xy-2x-s+4)dx$

$\Rightarrow f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{32} \int_{2}^{s}(xy-2x-s+4)dx$

$\Rightarrow f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{32}[\frac{x^{2}y}{2} - x^2 - xy + 4x]_{r=2}^{r=s}$

$\Rightarrow f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{64} (y^3-4y^2+8y-8)$

$\Rightarrow f_{X,Y}(X = x \mid Y = y) = \frac{\frac{1}{32}(xy - 2x - y + 4)} {\frac{1}{64}(y^3-4y^2+8y-8)}$

then provided $y=5$

$\Rightarrow f_{X,Y}(X = x \mid Y = y) \frac{2}{57}(3r-1); 2 \le x \le 5$

Now going back to $P(X \gt 3 \mid Y = 5)$

$\Rightarrow P(X \gt 3 \mid Y = 5) = \int_{3}^{5} f_{X,Y}(X = x \mid Y = 5)dx$

$\Rightarrow P(X \gt 3 \mid Y = 5) = \int_{3}^{5} \frac{2}{57}(3x-1)dx$

$\Rightarrow P(X \gt 3 \mid Y = 5) = \frac{2}{57} \int_{3}^{5} (3x-1)dx$

$\Rightarrow P(X \gt 3 \mid Y = 5) = \frac{2}{57} [\frac{3x^2}{2}-x]_{r=3}^{r=5}$

$\implies P(X \gt 3 \mid Y = 5) = \frac{46}{57} = .807$

Comment: Well, the idea is okay, but the final answer is incorrect. Also, why have you introduced the symbols $r,s$ ? All calculations would be easier to check if you had noticed that $xy-2x-2y+4=(x-2)(y-2)$.  For instance: $$\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= \int_2^y \tfrac 1{32}(x-2)(y-2)\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=\tfrac 1{32}(y-2)\int_2^y (x-2)\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=\tfrac 1{32}(y-2)\int_0^{(y-2)} z\,\mathrm d z&&z=x-2, \mathrm d z=\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=\tfrac 1{64}(y-2)^3\end{align}$$

Comment: @Graham thanks for the insight! I appreciate your time.