# Specify the area of interest to find the marginal pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose the following joint pdf:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{3}{2}x$ if $1\leq x \leq 2$ and $0 \leq y \leq x$.

Note that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 0$ otherwise.

I am told to calculate the marginal pdf for $Y$, that is, $f_Y(y)$. In this case, I have to fix $y$ and integrate over $x$.

I calculated $f_Y(y)$ as $\int_{y}^{2} \frac{3}{2}x~ dx$. But in fact it should be solved as $\int_{1}^{y} \frac{3}{2}x~ dx$. Can someone explain me why the set of interest is $\int_{1}^{y}$ and not $\int_{y}^{2}$? And can you help me first drawing the region of interest?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: If you drew the support of thr pdf then you could imagine how to integrate when $y$ is fixed...

Comment: Yes but I need help to draw the support for the pdf

Comment: The support is between 1 and 2 in $x$ and greater than 0 and less than $x$ in $y$.

Comment: Can you see that hut now?

Comment: Yes I know but can you please just draw the area of interest for me? thank you

Comment: Sorry, I am sitting in the sauna, I cannot draw...

Comment: The way you calculated $f_Y(y)$ is correct for every $y\in[1,2]$. Who told you that it was not?

Comment: @drhab by following the question number 1-b in (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn06.pdf) and its solution 1-b in (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn05_sol.pdf), the professor solved it as $\int_1^y$ and which seems not logical for me!

Comment: @zoli jajajajajajaja you made my day. okay have fun:p

Comment: @drhab can you please add an answer by drawing the area of interest for me. I just want to ensure if I have solved it correctly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The problem and its solution *do not match* (so your mislead). They solve the problem for a function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ that is defined as $ax$ if $1\leq x\leq 2$ and $x\leq y\leq 2$. This is not the function that is mentioned in the problem. Actually the function you mentioned in your question (based on "wrong" solution $a=\frac23$) is not even a PDF, because its integral exceeds $1$.

Comment: @drhab I have erroneously written $2/3$ instead of $3/2$. I edited my question. So do you think it should be $x<y<2$ and not $0<y<x$? so do you think the professor made an error in the problem question (he erroneously asked for $0<y<x$ instead of $x<y<2$)?

Comment: It must be $a=\frac37$. The professor made a mistake by publishing the solution of another question.

Comment: @drhab you are correct. Shame on me. It is my fault. I looked to other solution pdf!!! the solution pdf for this problem is https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn06_sol.pdf

Comment: I spend one day by thinking why I am not able to solve the problem correctly!!! and so I discovered now that I opened the erroneous pdf solution that corresponds to another problem pdf.

Comment: You can look at this page https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/

Comment: Problem solved then. Do not feel too much of shame  (4 bytes is enough). You can also learn from situations like this. Good luck with your study of probabilities.

Comment: @drhab thank you for your kind comment. And thank you for your time.