# Joint density function, Find $P( X>Y)$

Tags: probability

Random variables X and Y have joint density function $f(x,y)$= $e^{-x-y}$, for x,y>0.

I have to find $P(X+Y<1)$ and $P(X>Y)$. I found $P(X+Y<1)$, but I don't know how to find $P(X>Y)$, what would be the upper and lower bound of the integral?

Comment: $P(X>Y) = P(X-Y>0)$. How did you find $P(X+Y < 1)$?

Comment: There is a simple symmetry argument to calculate $P(X \gt Y)$ given $P(X=Y)=0$

Answer (score 0):

The existence of joint density betrays that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables so that $P(X=Y)=0$.

The joint density itself betrays that $X$ and $Y$ are iid (actually both have standard exponential distribution).

This because we can write the density as $f(x)f(y)$ where $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

Then $P(X>Y)=P(Y<X)$ by symmetry.

Next to that we have $P(X<Y)+P(Y<X)=1$ so we conclude that $P(X>Y)=P(Y<X)=\frac12$.

Comment: Hello @drhab please can you help me for this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291176/specify-the-area-of-interest-to-find-the-marginal-pdf

Comment: @Christina Not excluded yet, but I never make promises like that. I am sure you will understand ;-).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time:)